# Filter application on Large Images gets slow

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

I need suggestions on how to solve this problem.
We are developing an image editing application using fabricjs. We also have developed the functionality to apply filters on images like the ones mentioned [here(along with the code)](http://fabricjs.com/image-filters).

They work perfectly fine on images with size of 1100px X 700px but if the image size exceeds this the filters take time before they get applied on the image. What can I do to make the filter's application faster for large images?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should start to look at version 2.0
Generally filters are faster and where possible webgl is used.

http://fabricjs.com/image-filter-webgl